# How to make bootstrap navbar to push down the whole page on mobile menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Although there is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971372/how-can-i-get-twitter-bootstraps-mobile-navbar-to-overlay-the-content-on-the-pag), his problem seems like my solution but I have no Idea to make progress.

I'm using bootstrap navbar that is fixed to the top to make.. navigation menu.
on mobile pages(where screen size is small), I have to bring them by pressing some menu button on top-rightmost corner.

however when the menu pops up, I'd like it to **push the page down, instead of overlaying it.**

here's my code.. what edit should I make to get rid of overlaying?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#!/">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#!/notice">notice</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!/board">board</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                <a id="a-logout" href="#!/logout">sign out</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="#!/user">Your page</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have `navbar-fixed-top`, the navbar will overlay the page. Removing that class in your mobile view is enough?

Comment: @azeós but I need that class to fix my navbar to the top of the screen(not to the top of the page)

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13309315/1095101. But what would happen if you scroll to the middle of the page an open the navbar? what will you push down?

Comment: @azeós Maybe I'll just give up the `navbar-fixed-top`

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you have defined the height of `.navbar` which is forcing the collapsed menu to overlay. Just change height in `.navbar` to `min-height`

```
.navbar
{
    min-height:65px; // or value of your desire
}
```

If not solved kindly post your CSS too.

Answer (score 2):

### 1st version. Setting `padding-top` by two constants

1. [Body padding is required](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#callout-navbar-fixed-top-padding) when you use a navbar with the `.navbar-fixed-top` class:

   > The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the `<body>`.
   >
   > By default, the navbar is 50px high.
   >
   > Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.
2. [Collapse events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events) help to change the value of the `padding-top` property:

   > `show.bs.collapse` fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
   >
   > `hide.bs.collapse` is fired immediately when the hide method has been called.
3. You can copy `transition` properties [from the `.collapsing` class](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css).
4. User can increase the width of the window while the menu stays expanded. In this case it is necessary to reduce the `padding-top` property for the `body`. For example by media-query and `!important`.

So let's define `padding-top` value using two constants - `50px` and `235px`.

```js
var selectBody = $('body');

/* 2. */
$('.navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  selectBody.css('padding-top', '235px');
})
$('.navbar-collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  selectBody.css('padding-top', '50px');
})
```

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
  /* 1. */
  padding-top: 50px;

  /* 3. */
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
       -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
          transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .35s;
       -o-transition-duration: .35s;
          transition-duration: .35s;
  -webkit-transition-property: padding-top;
       -o-transition-property: padding-top;
          transition-property: padding-top;
}

/* 4. */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 50px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Left 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Left 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Right 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Right 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Header 1</h1><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p>
  <h2>Header 2</h2><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p>
  <h3>Header 3</h3><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

### 2nd version. Using `outerHeight()`

Let's set the `padding-top` value by [the `outerHeight()` function](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/).

And let's collapse navbar when user increase the screen width to `768px` or more.

http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/PGbZPG

```js
var selectBody = $('body');
var selectNavbarCollapse = $('.navbar-collapse');

var heightNavbarCollapsed = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true);
var heightNavbarExpanded = 0;

paddingSmall();

selectNavbarCollapse.on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  if (heightNavbarExpanded == 0) heightNavbarExpanded = heightNavbarCollapsed + $(this).outerHeight(true);
  paddingGreat();
})
selectNavbarCollapse.on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  paddingSmall();
})

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ((document.documentElement.clientWidth > 767) && selectNavbarCollapse.hasClass('in')) {
    selectNavbarCollapse.removeClass('in').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    paddingSmall();
  }
});

function paddingSmall() {
  selectBody.css('padding-top', heightNavbarCollapsed + 'px');
}

function paddingGreat() {
  selectBody.css('padding-top', heightNavbarExpanded + 'px');
}
```

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
       -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
          transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .35s;
       -o-transition-duration: .35s;
          transition-duration: .35s;
  -webkit-transition-property: padding-top;
       -o-transition-property: padding-top;
          transition-property: padding-top;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Left 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Left 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Right 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Right 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Header 1</h1><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p>
  <h2>Header 2</h2><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p>
  <h3>Header 3</h3><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
$('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.after-navbar').css('margin-top','230px');
});
```

Please Find working example here http://jsfiddle.net/LptkL/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to animate the body down.  I'd need to see more code to get this exact, and you'd need jQuery, but try this...

```
$('.navbar').on('click', function() {
    var height = ($('.navbar-collapse.in').length == 0) ? $(this).height() : 0;
    $('body').css({
        marginTop: height
    })
});
```

**UPDATE:** include code to account for if the nav is in or out.  This really isn't going to work well since you'll need to fire most of this code after the nav has animated in.  You can however remove $(this).height() and replace with a hard-coded pixel amount equal to the height of your nav.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for max-height:

**CSS**

```
.navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

This way you will have a nice scroll bar for your menu.

You can ajust the `max-height` depending on the `window` size using the `resize` event on JS.

Answer (score 1):

Change `navbar-fixed-top` to `navbar-static-top`.